# Setup Nhost.io client session with refreshToken in Node.js server

Tags: node.js, jwt, nhost

I am building a Node.js server (no meta-frameworks such as Next.js) and I want to setup the [Nhost](https://nhost.io) client with a refresh token that comes from a passwordless sign in link to make authenticated requests.

I am trying the following and it doesn't work:

```
import { NhostClient } from '@nhost/nhost-js'

const nhost = new NhostClient({
  region: 'myregion',
  subdomain: 'mysubdomain'
})

const refreshToken = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
const refreshSession = await nhost.auth.refreshSession(refreshToken)

// The session is received properly in `refreshSession.session`.
nhost.auth.client.start({ initialSession: refreshSession.session })

// The request doesn't resolve as it should.
const myResponse = await nhost.graphql.request('mygraphql')
```

How can I fix this? Thank you! ‍♂️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a new authentication with refresh token coming from passwordless sign in:

```
import { NhostClient } from '@nhost/nhost-js'

const nhost = new NhostClient({
  region: 'myregion',
  subdomain: 'mysubdomain'
})

const refreshToken = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
const refreshSession = await nhost.auth.refreshSession(refreshToken)

if (!refreshSession.session) {
  throw new Error('Invalid refresh token.')
}

// Store `refreshSession.session` in cookie or cache for later use.

nhost.graphql.setAccessToken(refreshSession.session.accessToken)

const myResponse = await nhost.graphql.request('mygraphql')
```

For an already authenticated user using the session from a cookie or cache:

```
import { type NhostSession, NhostClient } from '@nhost/nhost-js'

const nhost = new NhostClient({
  region: 'myregion',
  subdomain: 'mysubdomain'
})

const session = getNHostSessionFromCookieOrCache() as NHostSession

nhost.auth.client.start({ initialSession: session })
nhost.graphql.setAccessToken(session.accessToken)

const myResponse = await nhost.graphql.request('mygraphql')
```